# Java object returns null outside of for loop

Tags: java, arrays

```
public Account [] search(double bal){

boolean flag=false;
Account [] tmp = new Account[account.length];

//Loop until the end of the account array.
for(int i=0;i<account.length && account[i]!=null;i++)
{
if(account[i].getBal()==bal)
   {
           tmp[i]=account[i];
           System.out.println(tmp[i]);  //here returns correct value
           flag=true;
       }
   }


   System.out.println(tmp[0]);  //here returns null

   return tmp;
}
```

Hi. I am pretty new to Java.

System.out.println(tmp[i]) returns correct Account obj and prints the values.

But why is System.out.println(tmp[0]) returns null outside for loop?

Comment: Take out pen and paper and run through your program marking the value of each object.

Comment: Alternatively, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If first condition is false,then always `temp[0]` will be null.

```
 if(account[i].getBal()==bal)
   {
           tmp[i]=account[i];
           System.out.println(tmp[i]);  //here returns correct value
           flag=true;
       }
```

Because in this code, if first condition is correct only,it will go into the `"if"` condition, then assign the value of `account[i]` to `temp[0]`. otherwise it will be null ever.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you were just a little confused -

```
public Account[] search(double bal) {
  int flag = 0;
  Account[] tmp = new Account[account.length];

  // Loop until the end of the account array.
  for (int i = 0; i < account.length && account[i] != null; i++) {
    tmp[i] = account[i]; // I assume you wanted to "copy" account.
    if (account[i].getBal() == bal) {
      System.out.println(tmp[i]); // here returns correct
                                  // value
      flag = i;
    }
  }

  /* becasue 0 is not i */
  System.out.println(tmp[flag]); // use "flag"

  // Honestly, you should use -
  // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29
  // System.arraycopy(account, 0, tmp, 0, account.length);
  return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
    if(account[i].getBal()==bal)
   {
           tmp[i]=account[i];
           System.out.println(tmp[i]);  //here returns correct value
           flag=true;
       }
   }
```

If the condition was false when counter i == 0, then tmp[0] will be null eventually. You can use ArrayList with the tmp variable, then convert it to Account array like the following:

```
public Account [] search(double bal){


ArrayList<Account> tmp = new ArrayList<Account>();

for(int i=0;i<account.length && account[i]!=null;i++)
{
if(account[i].getBal()==bal)
   {
           tmp.add(account[i]);
           System.out.println(tmp[i]);  //here returns correct value
       }
   }

   Account resultArray[] = new Account[tmp.size()];
   resultArray = tmp.toArray(resultArray);

   return resultArray;
}
```